# What is the oldest version of MacOS X / iOS I can compile for using XCode 5 under Maverick?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, version

What is the oldest version of MacOS X / iOS I can compile for using XCode 5 under Maverick?

I would like to compile for oldest version of iOS 3.1.3 in Cocoa Touch
and also to compile for 10.6, or if possible 10.4 in Cocoa

Comment: Why do you want to target iOS 3? 80% of devices are running iOS 7.

Comment: Some of my phones are release iPhones from June/July 2007, I would like to make my projects run on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can go back to iOS 4.3 and OS X 10.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can't it in xCode 5. because xCode 5 have available simulator start from iOS 5.0.

so far min deployment target iOS 3 available in up to xCode 4.4.1.

Armv6 not available in xCode 5

you can run iOS 3.0 only xCode 4.2 other than xcode 5 you can't do it

[xcode-42-building-for-ios-31x-and-older-devices](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/01/10/xcode-42-building-for-ios-31x-and-older-devices.html)

You can set min deployment target iOS 4.3 in xcode 5

[image]

more information  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode